# Split a comma-separated field in XSLT and select or limit the number of fields

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I wish to include data from an XML element that is in CSV format.

Ironically, the output is a CSV file.

The real problem is that the CSV format permits 4 keywords.

```
,,,,,,one,two,three,four,,,,,,     OK
,,,,,,one,two,three,four,five,,,,, WRONG
,,,,,,one,two,,,,,,,,              OK
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                    OK
```

Therefore the usual suspect `<value-of select="keywords"/>` wont work because the number of values in the element is variable, most often NONE sometimes 3 to 5 entries.

Such as

```
<keywords>one,two,three,four</keywords>
<keywords>one,two,three,four,five</keywords>
<keywords>one,two</keywords>
<keywords></keywords>
```

Is there any way of using XSLT to turn this CSV array into an XML element, and then targeting each one as such. Empty values would be perfectly fine.

```
<xsl:value-of select="fubar1"/><xsl:value-of select="','"/>
<xsl:value-of select="keyword[1]"/><xsl:value-of select="','"/>
<xsl:value-of select="keyword[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="','"/>
<xsl:value-of select="keyword[3]"/><xsl:value-of select="','"/>
<xsl:value-of select="keyword[4]"/><xsl:value-of select="','"/>
<xsl:value-of select="fubar3"/><xsl:value-of select="','"/>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your XML data looks like. Is it the sample following "Such as", or is that the output? If your input has CSV data fields within XML elements then it sounds like what you want to do is possible using XSLT, but I would much prefer a scripting language for this. Are you tied to XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a straightforward recursive version:

```
<xsl:template name="cvsmaxkey">
    <xsl:param name="keys" />
    <xsl:param name="nrofkeys" /> 
    <xsl:param name="pos" />
    <xsl:if test="$pos &lt;= $nrofkeys">
        <xsl:if test="$pos > 1 and $keys">
            <xsl:value-of select="','" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($keys, ',')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($keys,',')" />
                <xsl:call-template name="cvsmaxkey">
                    <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="substring-after($keys,',')" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="nrofkeys" select="$nrofkeys" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos +1" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$keys">
                <xsl:value-of select="$keys" />
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(',,,,,,,,,,,', 1,$nrofkeys - $pos)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="keywords">
    <xsl:call-template name="cvsmaxkey">
        <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="nrofkeys" select="4" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//keywords"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Which generate the following output (with const amount of separators (,):

```
one,two,three,four
one,two,three,four
one,two,,
,,,
```

Comment: superb. works like a fracking charm. and easy to implement. it seems its limited by the number of commas inside the `<xsl:value-of select="substring(',,,,,,,,,,,', 1,$nrofkeys - $pos)"/>` but fine for most situations. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**I. Here is a simple XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "tokenize(., ',')[.][not(position() gt 4)]" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <keywords>one,two,three,four</keywords>
    <keywords>one,two,three,four,five</keywords>
    <keywords>one,two</keywords>
    <keywords></keywords>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
one,two,three,four
one,two,three,four
one,two
```

---

**II. A Non-recursive XSLT 1.0 solution**

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNodes"
   select="$vDoc//node() | $vDoc//@* | $vDoc//namespace::*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="vNorm" select="normalize-space(translate(.,',',' '))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vCount" select=
    "string-length($vNorm) -string-length(translate($vNorm, ' ', ''))+1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vTextToPrint">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="not($vCount >4)"><xsl:value-of select="$vNorm"/></xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vNodes[not(position() > string-length($vNorm))]">
              <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
              <xsl:variable name="vheadSubstr" select="substring($vNorm,1,$vPos)"/>
              <xsl:if test=
              "substring($vNorm, $vPos, 1) = ' '
              and
                string-length($vheadSubstr)
               -
                string-length(translate($vheadSubstr, ' ',''))

                = 4">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($vNorm,1,$vPos -1)"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="translate($vTextToPrint, ' ', ',')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
one,two,three,four
one,two,three,four
one,two
```

Comment: first off, thanks a lot mr xml. the 2.0 solution is remarkably simple and easy to follow. but i must go with the confusing 1.0. how does one apply that a typical xml data,  such as <name>Name</name><address>Address</address><keywords>one,two,three,four,five</keywords><city>City</city><zip>XXXXX</zip> for example within <xsl:template match="/" >
 <xsl:apply-templates select="t" />
</xsl:template>

Comment: @user1869322, Please, just invoke your XSLT 1.0 processor with the provided XSLT 1.0 transformation on the provided XML document. Then you'll get the provided result.

Comment: yes. that works very well. thank you. i need to fill up those extra commas though. ie. not `one,two` but `one,two,,`

Comment: @user1869322, You are welcome. The extra commas can be output in separate <xsl:value-of> (or other) instructions.